# Pre Fill Product Name on Salesforce Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, product

When the user click New button on Salesforce Product (As on below screen),

[image: New Button]

I need to Pre Fill the Product Name,

[image: Product Name]

I did something similar to Opportunity standard object using a Lightning Component (force:createRecord)  by Overriding the New button. But unfortunately on Products, there is no way to override the default behavior using a Lightning component.

Comment: You want the field pre-populated with what?

Comment: Hi galls, thanks for the reply. I need to set a custom test like "Product Name will be Updated Later". I am planning to get this text from a Custom Label. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi @glls Do you have any update? Appreciate your help.

Comment: you will have to create a custom lightning component to achieve this